# Spring boot crud no explicit mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have made a crud application, from where I can add a user manually (I am working with SpringBoot, Java, Thymleaf and PostgresQL. When I add a user the data is added to PostgresSql, but the fallback page is not working. So I cannot see a list of users, the one that already in there and also not the one I created.

I will share my code:

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class JustTesting {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public JustTesting(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/signup")
    public String showSignUpForm(AppUser appUser) {
        return "add-user";
    }

    @PostMapping("/adduser")
    public String addUser(@Valid AppUser appUser, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "add-user";
        }

        userRepository.save(appUser);
        model.addAttribute("users", userRepository.findAll());
        return "redirect:/view-user";
    }

    @GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String showUpdateForm(@PathVariable("id") long id, Model model) {
        AppUser appUser = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid user Id:" + id));
        model.addAttribute("appUser", appUser);
        return "update-user";
    }

    @PostMapping("/update/{id}")
    public String updateUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, @Valid AppUser appUser, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            appUser.setUserId(id);
            return "update-user";
        }

        userRepository.save(appUser);
        model.addAttribute("appUsers", userRepository.findAll());
        return "redirect:/view-user";
    }

    @GetMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, Model model) {
        AppUser appUser = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid user Id:" + id));
        userRepository.delete(appUser);
        model.addAttribute("users", userRepository.findAll());
        return "view-user";
    }
}
```

Than we have the Thymeleaf page: add-user

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Add User</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="/css/shards.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


</head>
<body>
<div class="container my-5">
    <h2 class="mb-5">New User</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form action="#" th:action="@{/adduser}" th:object="${appUser}" method="post">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="userId" class="col-form-label">userId</label>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{userId}" class="form-control" id="userId" placeholder="userId">
                        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('userId')}" th:errors="*{userId}" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="userName" class="col-form-label">userName</label>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{userName}" class="form-control" id="userName" placeholder="userName">
                        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('userName')}" th:errors="*{userName}" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="encrytedPassword" class="col-form-label">encrytedPassword</label>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{encrytedPassword}" class="form-control" id="encrytedPassword" placeholder="encrytedPassword">
                        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('encrytedPassword')}" th:errors="*{encrytedPassword}" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 mt-5">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add User">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the view-user:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Users</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="/css/shards.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head>

<body>
<div th:switch="${appUsers}" class="container my-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2 th:case="null">No users yet!</h2>
            <div th:case="*">
                <h2 class="my-5">Users</h2>
                <table class="table table-striped table-responsive-md">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>userId</th>
                        <th>userName</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="appUser : ${appUsers}">
                        <td th:text="${appUser.userId}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${appUser.userName}"></td>
                        <td><a th:href="@{/edit/{userId}(id=${appUser.userId})}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-appUser-edit ml-2"></i></a></td>
                        <td><a th:href="@{/delete/{userId}(id=${appUser.userId})}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-appUser-times ml-2"></i></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <p class="my-5"><a href="/signup" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-appUser-plus ml-2"></i></a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also have a model page called AppUser und a Repository. I am a beginner, I just managed to make a working login and I want I would like to get working is that if you login in as an admin you can add users that can log in as well.

Maybe someone can help :) Danielle

Comment: can you provide the code for the /view-user endpoint?

Comment: Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Aug 27 11:19:13 CEST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: I could fix this by removing the redirects, now I get an error when I want do delete or edit the user I created:

{"timestamp":"08-27-2020 22:40:38","message":"Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"{userId}\"","details":"uri=/edit/%7BuserId%7D"}